# How to change the values of points in polyline dynamically using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

How to change the points values of polyline dynamically. I know it can done something like this using javascript. But how to do in Jquery?

```
var id=document.getElementById("id_Value");
id.points[4].y=233;
```

I have attached a jsfiddle for your reference. [JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/9uhhLsx5/)

Comment: *"I have attached a jsfiddle for your reference."* Have you?

Comment: By the way, jQuery *is* a JavaScript framework. If you can do that in JavaScript, what's the question?

Comment: @ssice I know I know how to do in javascript. But how to do in jquery?

Comment: You could use jquery for the first part but you'd need to then get the underlying DOM node (via [0]) for the second part. Seems a bit pointless no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery equivalent of your vanilla Javascript code would be:

```
var id = $("#id_Value")[0];
id.points[4].y=233;
```

Be aware that there are many problems you may strike when using jQuery to manipulate SVG.  jQuery is only designed to work with HTML, not SVG.  There are many jQuery functions that don't work on SVG elements.